# Getting name of class member

Tags: c#

I have a class `Trigger` with some members of type `SimpleAction`:

```
public SimpleAction OnOver;
public SimpleAction OnOut;
public SimpleAction OnDown;
public SimpleAction OnUp;
public SimpleAction OnClick;
public SimpleAction OnHold;
```

Now, from another class I'm doing this:

```
MemberInfo[] members = triggerScript.GetType().GetMembers();
    foreach (MemberInfo item in members) {
            Debug.Log(item.Name);
    }
```

In log massages I can see list of names of all members of `Trigger` class. OnOver, OnOut atc are in that list too. But how can I separate members of type `SimpleAction` from others?
`item.DeclaringType` is type of `Trigger`
`item.MemberType` is "field" for tham.
`item.ReflectedType` is `Trigger` too.
**How can I get a member list of `SimpleAction` type?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use method `GetFields` then filter field with `FieldType` is `SimpleAction`

```
 FieldInfo[] fields = triggerScript.GetType()
            .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(field => field.FieldType == typeof (SimpleAction))
            .ToArray();

 foreach (var field in fields)
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use GetFields instead of GetMembers, then you can filter based on .FieldType == typeof(SimpleAction).